# how to flatten 2D list and add a separator character using zip and list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, python-zip

I'm trying to write a statement in python that turns this input (for example):

```
[[3,4],[1],[1,2]]
```

into this output:

```
 [3,4,-,1,-,1,2]
```

using only zip and list comprehension

this is my code:

```
a = [[1,2],[1],[3,4]]
result = [j for i in zip(a,'-'*len(a)) for j in i]

print(result)
```

but all I get is:

```
[[1, 2], '-', [1], '-', [3, 4], '-']
```

and my output should be this:

```
[1, 2, '-', 1, '-', 3, 4]
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
a = [[1,2],[1],[3,4]]
result = [a for i in zip(a,'-'*len(a)) for j in i for a in j]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, '-', 1, '-', 3, 4, '-']
```

This also works if you don't want the last `'-'` to be included:

```
a = [[1,2],[1],[3,4]]
result = [a for i in zip(a, '-'*len(a)) for j in i for a in j][:-1]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, '-', 1, '-', 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! how do you take out the last item without result.pop() in that same statement?

Comment: ok, I added a section to my answer to address that

Answer (score 1):

Adding another `for` clause and prepending the separator before each inner list except the first:

```
[k for i in zip([[]]+['-']*len(a), a) for j in i for k in j]
```

Result ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7DoAgEAV7T7GdoFj4KWw8yWYLCo0LBglioZdH0eIlk7zJ@Cuuu@tHH1LSMAFiqzpS2L7r1UBUhPk4t5gvC8segIEd3OwFIlGNZVNStc1OaKlAy08xWeEPbUZDhQ/sovhbMqUH)):

```
[1, 2, '-', 1, '-', 3, 4]
```

The `zip(...)` gives these three pairs:

```
([], [1, 2])
('-', [1])
('-', [3, 4])
```

Then `j` is the inner lists/strings, and `k` is the numbers/characters, so we can use `k` for the result elements of the list comprehension.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for! can you explain a little how it works?

Comment: @AlexButane Added a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```py
a = [[3,4],[1],[1,2]]

result = []
for i,l in enumerate(a):
    result += l + ["-"] * (i!=len(a)-1)

print(result) # [3, 4, '-', 1, '-', 1, 2]
```

Comment: You right but it's not a list comprehension and I'm not sure they allowed us to use Enumerate either

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that reuse part of your code and just use the itertools library to achieve your goal:

```
# import chain
from itertools import chain

a = [[1,2],[1],[3,4]]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(
         [j for i in zip(a,'-'*len(a)) for j in i]))[:-1]
print(result)
```

and your output:

```
[1, 2, '-', 1, '-', 3, 4]
```